# Autofilter - dynamically linking the operator to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

First post! Hello everyone :)

Hoping for a bit of help using VBA/Autofilter. I am creating a screening tool that does the following-

1) user inputs a bunch of parameters into the tab "ScreenerOptions" using a combination of dropdowns and numerical inputs
2) selections in "ScreenerOptions" drive VBA code to Autofilter a table, which is in a seperate tab, "Master1"

I want the parameters to be linked dynamically to cells, so whatever option is chosen in a drop down drives the autofilter. I have got everything dynamically linked EXCEPT the operator (eg xlFilterValues, xlTop10Percent etc).

Below is a subset of the parameters in my screener.

[image]

Here is code that works:

```
Sub Test()

With Sheets("Master1")

    'FCF Yield, row 14 in screener - if the user leaves the field blank
    If Worksheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 5) = "" Then

    'Then all rows in the table are displayed for this column
    'Column6 in the screener is pulling in the relevant
    'column number in the table based on MATCH formula
    Worksheets("Master1").Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=Sheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 6)

    'If a parameter is entered, filter is applied
    'Criteria reference based on inputs in Screener Options Columns C (3) and E (5)

    Else

        'Formula in screener tool column 8 tells you if dropdown uses a value operator
        'e.g. ">", "=" returns 0
        'dropdowns containing text 'percent' return a 1

        'If 0 is returned, use operator xlOr to return numberical values and blanks
        If Worksheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 8).Value = 0 Then

        Worksheets("Master1").Range("A4").AutoFilter _
        Field:=Sheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 6), _
        Criteria1:=Sheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 3).Value & _
        Worksheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 5).Value, _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""

        Else
        'If 1 is returned, use operators xlTop10Percent, xlBottom10Percent as selected
        Worksheets("Master1").Range("A4").AutoFilter _
        Field:=Sheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 6), _
        Criteria1:=Worksheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 5).Value, _
        **Operator:=xlTop10Percent**
        End If

    End If

End With

Worksheets("Master1").Activate

End Sub
```

However, when I change the last operator to link to a cell instead of hard-coding xlTop10Percent:

```
Operator:=Worksheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 3).Value
```

I get the error:

> Run-time '1004: Autofilter method of Range class failed.

Can anyone help? It's so closed to being finished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string "xlTop10Percent" is just a string - there's no mechanism in VBA to directly convert it to the value of the `xlTop10Percent` constant.

You can substitute it with the numeric value (5) though and that should work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilteroperator

If you want to use the "friendly" names in your table then you can create a lookup table on a worksheet to handle the conversion to the numeric values.

Comment: Thank you! Worked a treat. Can't believe I had no idea about the numerical values ! Now I can sleep easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Well done for your first post !

About your code, I'm not an expert but i guess it comme from the fact that you assign a string value (like "dog", "hello" or "xlTop10Percent"

Actualy both lines are identical :

```
Operator:=Worksheets("ScreenerOptions").Cells(14, 3).Value
Operator:="xlTop10Percent"
```

Which is totally different from that :

```
Operator:=xlTop10Percent
```

Operator can take value rather than text, could you try by setting your cell(14,3) at 5 rather than a text ?

Should work, let me know !

take care !

Comment: Thank you, makes sense and the numbers worked a treat. Have a great evening!